# removing duplicates error, array[x] is not defined

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs, javascript-objects

I am trying to remove duplicates from data passed on from the Node. The function to fetch the data is:

```
getProducts(_) {
     const dev = "http://localhost:3008/api"
      fetch(dev) 
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
       /* this.setState
        ({
          data: data.data
        })
      })*/
     this.removeDuplicates(data) 
      })
    }
```

My remove duplicates function is:

```
removeDuplicates(arr){ 
    let array = arr.data
  console.log(array)
    array.sort((a,b) => {return a.webservice - b.webservice}) 
  let length = array.length 
   for ( var i = 0; 
          i < length; 
          i++ ){
            let x = i+1
           console.log(array[x].webservice)
    /*  if (array[i].webservice == array[x].webservice){
        delete array[i]
      }*/
     // console.log(array)
      }
  }
```

When I console.log the `data` - it returns the array of object as expected. 
When I console.log the `array[i].webservice` - it returns the webservice 
But when I try to do the same for `array[x].webservice` (which is i+1) it returns array[x] is undefined fatal error but still console.logs the data.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I would recommend using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy).
It has the filtering functionality you are looking for.

Comment: could you show some sample content of `data`

Comment: A rule of thumb is to never mutate the array you are looping or change the index. You are doing both here. A reduce function would be better to filter out uniques. The array.reduce function provided by @user615274 is a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this part of your code more closely:

```
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++ ){
  let x = i+1;
  // ...etc....
}
```

Let's say the length of the array is 3. When i = 2, it is less than 3, so the loop will execute; x = i + 1 = 2 + 1 = 3. Then you're trying to access `array[3]` -- but an array with length 3 only goes from 0 to 2! That will be trying to access beyond the bounds of your array, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove duplicates from an array as follows,

Assuming your data is similar to this

```
const data = [
  { webservice: "a" },
  { webservice: "b" },
  { webservice: "c" },
  { webservice: "b" },
  { webservice: "d" },
];
```

In this example the item with webservice with value `b` and index 3 will be excluded for repeating

```js
const data = [
  { webservice: "a" },
  { webservice: "b" },
  { webservice: "c" },
  { webservice: "b" },
  { webservice: "d" },
];

const output = data.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  if (!accumulator.some(element => element.webservice === current.webservice)) {
    accumulator.push(current);
  }

  return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

I hope I have interpreted your question properly

Comment: You could also just reduce it to an object with webservice as the key, the data as the value and return object.values at the end. Saves a lot of loops

Comment: If you are using ES6/ES2015 or later you can do it this way:

```const unique = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.webservice))];
```